# Local and docker development IP resolution for one container to reach another

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Let's assume we have two backend apps, where `backend_for_frontend` needs to fetch some data from `api`.

If both apps are run in docker or `api` runs in docker and `backend_for_frontend` runs locally, `backend_for_frontend` can use `http://host.docker.internal:3001/api` address to connect to api.

If both apps are run locally(not in docker) then `backend_for_frontend` needs to use `http://127.0.0.1:3001/api` for `api` connection.

Issue is that when we switch running `api` between docker or locally, we need to use different ip for `backend_for_frontend` that needs to be manually changed because `backend_for_frontend` doesn't know how we run `api`.

Is there a way to resolve this ip somehow automatically or use ip as env variable that will work in any case? Basically I want to run `backend_for_frontend` and `api` in any combination, while connection url for `backend_for_frontend` still can be resolved not by hand.

---

`docker.compose` example:

```
services:
  api:
    ports:
      - 3001:3001

  backend_for_frontend:
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very common configuration scenario and you'll usually solve it by setting an environment variable in `backend_for_frontend` to the URL of the API.

Let's call the environment variable `API_URL`. Then you can do

```
services:
  api:
    ports:
      - 3001:3001

  backend_for_frontend:
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
    environment:
      - API_URL=http://api:3001/
```

Then, when you run the API locally, you'd change it to `http://host.docker.internal:3001/`.

You'll need to change your `backend_for_frontend` code to fetch the URL from the environment variable. There's no universal way of doing it and it depends on what language your `backend_for_frontend` is coded in.

If you have an URL that you want to be the default, you can add an `ENV` statement to the `backend_for_frontend` Dockerfile to set it. Then you only need to specify it in your docker-compose file when you want to override it.

Comment: I currently do it that way, but that forces me to change `backend_for_frontend` `API_URL` every time I decide to run `api` locally or not for debugging let's say. I hoped to find a way to setup it

Comment: your example gaved me an idea and it's seems to work in any configuration. Use `http://host.docker.internal:3001` when `backend_for_frontend` runs in docker and `http://0.0.0.0:3001` if not

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved via using hostname instead of using direct IP address to access the API.

this will give flexibility to use hostname regardless of API running locally or on Docker.

for example, it can be used http://api:3001/api as the base URL for the API in backend_for_frontend, and then set up Docker Compose file to define a hostname for the api service:

```
services:
  api:
    hostname: api
    ports:
      - 3001:3001

  backend_for_frontend:
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
```

Comment: then it fails if I run `backend_for_frontend` locally `request to http://api:3001/api/graphql`

Answer (score -2):

Hello it's just the same as if you don't dockerize, call them by your port and socket

Your first api will call by : http://localhost:3001

And the seconds will be
http://localhost:3002

P.s you can use a network so they are in an internal network

That's all

Comment: then it's will not work when run in docker, because localhost inside docker is not another container: `ERROR: request to http://localhost:3001/api failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3001`

Comment: I understand both docker run separately  and need with two different docker compose files

Comment: I use docker-compose, but if I stop api to run it locally - `backend_for_frontend` can no longer connect if I don't change api ip env variable